# backpropagation implemention

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, backpropagation

I am trying to implement the backpropagation algorithm with one hideen layer network.
If I don't run with batch I succeed and everything works fine.
But when I run with batch I get that the loss function is nan after number of iterations.

if I'll replace output layer softmax with sigmoid activation
Everything works as expected.

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import torchvision
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import time
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
from torch import nn, optim

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
  torchvision.datasets.MNIST('/files/', train=True, download=True,
                             transform=torchvision.transforms.Compose([
                               torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
                               torchvision.transforms.Normalize(
                                 (0.1307,), (0.3081,))
                             ])),
   batch_size=64,
    shuffle=True)

test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
  torchvision.datasets.MNIST('/files/', train=False, download=True,
                             transform=torchvision.transforms.Compose([
                               torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
                               torchvision.transforms.Normalize(
                                 (0.1307,), (0.3081,))
                             ])),
  batch_size=1, shuffle=True)


def sigmoid(s):
    return 1 / (1 + torch.exp(-s))

def sigmoidPrime(s):
    # derivative of sigmoid
    # s: sigmoid output
    return s * (1 - s)

def softmax(x):
    expo = torch.exp(x)
    expo_sum = torch.sum(torch.exp(x))
    return expo/expo_sum

class Neural_Network:
    def __init__(self, input_size=28*28, output_size=10, hidden_size=64):
        # parameters
        self.inputSize = input_size
        self.outputSize = output_size
        self.hiddenSize = hidden_size
        
        # weights
        self.W1 = torch.randn(self.inputSize, self.hiddenSize)
        self.b1 = torch.zeros(self.hiddenSize) 
        
        self.W2 = torch.randn(self.hiddenSize, self.outputSize)
        self.b2 = torch.zeros(output_size)
        
    def forward(self, X):
        self.z1 = torch.matmul(X, self.W1) + self.b1
        self.h = sigmoid(self.z1) 
        self.z2 = torch.matmul(self.h, self.W2) + self.b2
        return softmax(self.z2)

    
    def backward(self, X, y, y_hat, lr=0.1)
        batch_size = y.size(0)
        dl_dz2 = (1/batch_size)*(y_hat - y)  
        
        dl_dh = torch.matmul(dl_dz2, torch.t(self.W2))
        dl_dz1 = dl_dh * sigmoidPrime(self.h)
        
        self.W1 -= lr*torch.matmul(torch.t(X), dl_dz1)
        self.b1 -= lr*torch.matmul(torch.t(dl_dz1), torch.ones(batch_size))
        self.W2 -= lr*torch.matmul(torch.t(self.h), dl_dz2)
        self.b2 -= lr*torch.matmul(torch.t(dl_dz2), torch.ones(batch_size))

        size=0
        count=0
        for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(test_loader):
            size=size+target.shape[0]
            output = NN.forward(data.view(-1,784))
            for i in range(output.shape[0]):
               pred = torch.argmax(output[i]).view(1)
               if target[i] == pred:
                   count=count+1
       print(f"the accuracy of the model is {count/size}")
```